# CH4 + O2 => CO2 + 2H2, what's wrong with it?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, stoichiometry, combustion

It says in my textbook that:

$$\ce{CH4 + 2 O2 -> CO2 + 2 H2O}$$

which seems like a displacement reaction to me. Shouldn't the reaction be:

$$\ce{CH4 + O2 -> CO2 + 2 H2}$$

since $\ce{4H}$ are displaced by $\ce{O2}$ (becoming $\ce{2 H2}$), which makes the reaction balanced?

Why is the reaction $\ce{CH4 + O2 -> CO2 + H2O}$, which is further balanced as my textbook says?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reaction as you state it is correct only if there will react only one molecule of oxygen. But the reaction describes burning of methane which is supposed to be in the presence of excess of oxygen. Then not only methane is burnt, but also the arised hydrogen.

So in "first" step:

$\ce{CH_4 + O_2 -> CO_2 + 2H_2}$

but then the hydrogen will be also combusted in reaction :

$\ce{2H_2 + O_2 -> 2H_2O}$

so the overall reaction will be:

$\ce{CH_4 + 2O_2 -> CO_2 + 2H_2O}$

As was pointed out in the others answers the real mechanism of a methane combustion at a low oxygen pressure is more complicated:

[image: 49th AIAA Aerospace Sciences Meeting including the New Horizons Forum and Aerospace Exposition, 4-7 January 2011, Orlando, Florida]

49th AIAA Aerospace Sciences Meeting including the New Horizons Forum and Aerospace Exposition, 4-7 January 2011, Orlando, Florida, http://enu.kz/repository/2011/AIAA-2011-94.pdf

another:
[image: COMBUSTION AND FLAME 120:160–172 (2000)]
Intermediate Species Proﬁles in Low-Pressure Methane/Oxygen Flames Inhibited by 2-H Heptaﬂuoropropane: Comparison of Experimental Data with Kinetic Modeling, http://www.nist.gov/el/fire_research/upload/Williams-Intermediate-Species-profiles-in-Low-pressure-Methaneoxygen-Flames-inhibited-by-2-heptafluoropropane.pdf

Comment: Thanks, you are the first guy who actually got it. I had another question: This is a displacement reaction or an oxidation reaction? I think it is displacement but I am not sure.

Comment: @ Klaus Warzecha - thanks I will

@ user2468338 - It is an oxidation reaction:

An oxidation/ reduction reaction is one where there is a change in the oxidation states of two or more species

Comment: Yeah, but displacement reaction is also a type of oxidation reaction right.

Comment: for example reaction of natrium hydroxide with hydrochloric acid is displacement reaction and not oxidation/reduction reaction.

Comment: @JaroslavKotowski Looks strange to me: with little oxygen, you fully oxidize carbon ($\ce{CO2}$). I've never thought that methane combustion could occur via two steps. Could you  please provide reference for that ?

Comment: @mannaia The world "first" is quoted because it is not real 1st step. The reaction in low oxygen pressure is a bit more complicated:
http://enu.kz/repository/2011/AIAA-2011-94.pdf
http://www.nist.gov/el/fire_research/upload/Williams-Intermediate-Species-profiles-in-Low-pressure-Methaneoxygen-Flames-inhibited-by-2-heptafluoropropane.pdf

Comment: @JaroslavKotowski Looks indeed very complex. Thanks for pointing it out in your last edit.

Comment: I kinda potentially disagree with the first sentence, because I’m not sure if $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2}$ will *actually* form given the lacking of oxygen, but other than that, this answer deserves the badge it is getting now.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the enthalpies of formation of $\ce{CO}$, $\ce{CO2}$, and $\ce{H2O}$, then the net enthalpies of reaction.  In a deficiency of oxygen, and trimmed by the temperature and kinetics versus equilibrium conditions, are you more likely to obtain $\ce{CO}$ plus $\ce{H2O}$ than free hydrogen?  Given less oxygen, soot and water?  Note reaction energetics below,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_gas  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syngas 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasification 
http://www.precision-combustion.com/High_Pressure_CPOX_methane.pdf

[image: enthalpies of formation]

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong. It's incomplete combustion.  It is one of a number of oxidizing reactions that can and will be occurring if you are burning this hydrocarbon in an oxygen-restricted environment. But the dominant reaction will be the one where the lowest energy state is reached. So you will likely wind up with one CO molecule, one water molecule and one hydrogen molecule instead.